# How can we get marker views to show up in front of ALL charts that may be rendered under it?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

If you have two charts that overlap, the chart in the back will render its MarkerViews underneath the more foreground chart. Is there a way we can prevent this?

[image: Double Donut Chart with Marker obscured by inner Chart]

I have followed the following process to create a "double donut" chart (outer donut pie chart, with an inner pie chart) with MPAndroid charts.

Create a Layout with 2 pieCharts, centered within the parent view:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/outer_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
       <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/inner_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am sizing the charts like so:

```
val innerChartHeight = (chartHeight * 0.85f).toInt()

val outerLayout = outerChart.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
outerLayout.height = chartHeight
outerLayout.setMargins(baseChartMargin)
outerChart.layoutParams = outerLayout

val innerLayout = innerChart.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
innerLayout.height = innerChartHeight
innerLayout.setMargins(baseChartMargin)
innerChart.layoutParams = innerLayout
```

I set the outer chart radius to 90% with a transparent center, and disable the legends so that the graph portions of the charts remain aligned:

```
outerChart.holeRadius = 90f
outerChart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
outerChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0)
outerChart.transparentCircleRadius = 90f

innerChart.legend.isEnabled = false
outerChart.legend.isEnabled = false
```

I set the marker views like below. `LabelValueMarkerView' is just a simple extension of`MarkerView` to render the Label as a header and the Value underneath with a specific layout resource:

```
val outerMarker = LabelValueMarkerView(
     context = requireContext(),
     labelFormatter = IndexedLabelFormatter(outerPieEntries.map { e -> e.label }),
     valueFormatter = RxPieValueFormatter(0))

outerMarker.chartView = outerChart
outerChart.marker = outerMarker

val innerMarker = LabelValueMarkerView(
     context = requireContext(),
     labelFormatter = IndexedLabelFormatter(innerPieEntries.map { e -> e.label }),
     valueFormatter = RxPieValueFormatter(0))

innerMarker.chartView = innerChart
innerChart.marker = innerMarker
```

I have tried the following without luck:

- Setting the elevation programmatically of the Marker as it is added to the chart. This did not have any effect.
- Ordering the outer chart AFTER the inner chart in the layout so that it's markers will render over the inner chart.  This works for the outer Markers, but you are unable to tap on the inner chart due to the outer chart capturing the events. Plus, if the inner chart markers offset under the outer chart we'll have the same problem anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving deeper into the source for `Chart` and `MarkerView`, I found that the markers are always drawn to the `Chart` canvas, so overlaying pie charts like this to achieve a double donut will always have this problem with markers.

It is possible this could be done with a subclass, and duplicating some of the marker rendering source to alter the render location. Since this could be quite fragile, and still may not work exactly as expected, I chose to capture the `OnChartValueSelected` events and render the selected data to a view that lives outside of the charts.